# Python 2.7.9 pip not installing pgzero

Tags: python, pip

I'm new to programming and am currently making my first game, but I ran into an issue. I installed normal Pygame, but I can't install Pygame Zero! When I type this command in the command prompt (I'm not showing my name for privacy reasons) to download `pgzero`, and this happens:

```
C:\users\(not showing this)> pip install pgzero
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Collecting pgzero
  Using cached pgzero-1.2.tar.gz (2.2 MB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Python27\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'c:\\users\\(not showing this)\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-install-edwrg0\\pgzero\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'c:\\users\\(not showing this)\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-install-edwrg0\\pgzero\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'c:\users\(not showing this)\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-edwrg0\pgzero\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: c:\users\(not showing this)\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-edwrg0\pgzero\
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "c:\users\(not showing this)\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-edwrg0\pgzero\setup.py", line 7, in <module>
        with open(path, encoding='utf8') as f:
    TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I'm pretty sure it's supposed to work but it just won't!

Comment: As it says in the traceback, Python 2 reached EOL. Using Python 2 is not only now a security risk, but also prone to a lot of bugs. Package maintainers have since moved to only support Python 3. You need to migrate as well.

Comment: So you're aware - EOL means Python 2 is no longer supported.

Comment: well I guess I have to rewrite my entire code then... It was based completely around the actor command

Comment: No, not necessarily. Firstly, check out the [official porting guide](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html) from the PSF. Then, once you've moved over, the packages that you're using should work just fine very similarly to how they did before.